# How to use % (modulus) in PHP to pick out every 1st, 2nd and 3rd result?

Tags: php, mysql, modulus

I am using a PHP while loop in order to get data from a database. Ignoring the data that I'm retrieving from the database and concentrating on the amount of records I have fetched, which is 4.

I want to be able to take the 1st record and insert it into a div called "div1" and take the 2nd record and insert it into a div called "div2", take the 3rd record and insert it into a div called "div3".

When it comes to the 4th record I would like to insert it in to the div called "div1" and so on.

I've managed to get every 3rd result, so skipping the 1st and 2nd record and being able to do it with the 3rd using a snippet from the below code:

```
if ($i % 3 < 2) {
```

I'm having trouble adapting that to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is some variation of

```
$targetDivNumber = ($i % 3) + 1;
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/S54XI).

Comment: Should i++ be used within the while loop?

Comment: This is the current of the PHP code that works. The code I've left out functions. `$i = 0;

while($allmodules = mysql_fetch_array($modules)) { 

if ($i % 3 < 2) { 

$divcode = '<div class="module-row1">';

} else { 

$divcode = '<div class="module-row2">'; 

} 

echo "" . $divcode . ""; 

$i++; 

?>`

Comment: @Ben Edit your answer, don't post code in comments, it won't look good.

Comment: @Ben: That looks about OK, but you want something like `$divCode = '<div class="module-row$targetDivNumber">';`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like (pseudo code)

```
if ($i % 3 = 0) {put in div1}
if ($i % 3 = 1) {put in div2}
if ($i % 3 = 2) {put in div3}
```

Comment: Should i++ be used within the while loop?

Comment: @Ben: If you didn't use i++ or something similar, i would have the same value on every iteration of the loop, which wouldn't make much sense. So, yeah, you need i++.

Answer (score 1):

With below code you can do this too:

```
$cont = 1;

while( fetch results from query )
{
     if($cont == 1)
         put in div 1;
     else if($cont == 2)
         put in div 2;
     else if($cont == 3)
         put in div3;

     $cont = $cont <= 3 ? $cont += 1 : 1;
}
```